# DBCP2 Timeout on borrow

Tags: java, datasource

Is there any way to configure `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` to set a timeout on borrowed connection in order to force them to rollback and return to the pool ?

I know these parameters but they does not fit my need :

> `removeAbandonedTimeout`: Remove the connection from the pool if it
> has not been used for longer than removeAbandonedTimeout.

> `maxConnLifetimeMillis`: Remove the connection from the pool after
> maxConnLifeTime

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is quite simple. I found Apache documention not clear about it but setting these values will make the deal :

`removeAbandonedOnMaintenance` (or `removeAbandonedOnBorrow`) + `removeAbandonedTimeout` + `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis`

Here is what the documentation states about abandoned connection :

> A connection is considered abandoned and eligible for removal if it
> has not been used for longer than removeAbandonedTimeout.

but by looking in the code they should have written :

> A connection is considered abandoned and eligible for removal if it
> has not been used for longer than removeAbandonedTimeout **and its current state is ALLOCATED**.

And that perfectly fits the need to remove borrowed abandoned connections.